Magento 1.9 deleting session from Plesk panel
The var/session folder constantly stores a large amount of data, which causes a lot of innode utilisation on the server,
I cannot enter the session folder because it is too big.
So I would like to ask how I can automatically delete session files every 24 hours, via a plesk command.
I have entered the following command: find /var/www/vhosts/mydomain/httpdocs/var/session -type f -ctime +8 -ctime -28 -delete
However, the command does not work correctly despite the fact that I have all the permissions. I don't want to use SSH or PHP but would like to solve this via cron jobs with a command on Plesk.
Thank you,
